# Silverlight and Facebook

Tags: .net, facebook, silverlight-4.0

How well does Silverlight play with Facebook?
Is there a special toolkit for facebook that I should use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Couple Facebook sdks support Silverlight:

- [Facebook C# SDK](http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/) latest beta supports Silverlight. I haven't used this SDK, but it appears to be in active development and I would give it a try first.
- [Facebook Developer Toolkit](http://facebooktoolkit.codeplex.com/) was used by Microsoft for their Facebook application, but it is poorely maintained and I had some issues with it.
- Graph api is pretty easy to work with, so you can just roll out your own sdk.

Comment: The Facebook C# SDK is the way to go. The Developer toolkit hasn't kept up with API changes. the C# SDK is specially mentioned here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/ee388574.aspx But it's still tricky to work with Silverlight. I'm generating the access token using the official JavaScript SDK, then passing that across a javascript -> managed call

Answer (score 0):

At PDC09, they demoed a Facebook application for Silverlight 4. It's available here:

http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2010/04/15/silverlight-client-for-facebook-updated-for-silverlight-4-release.aspx

Alas, no source code seems to be available. But you'll surely find ways around that. ;-)

Comment: So there is no toolkit for silverlight? whether official or not

Comment: The facebook API is documented at http://developers.facebook.com/ and can be used with any programming language. A more convenient version for Microsoft's frameworks including Silverlight seems to be available here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/ee388574.aspx

Answer (score 0):

There is a toolkit on [CodePlex](http://facebooktoolkit.codeplex.com/) but it's a bit out of date

and some good information on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/ee395718.aspx)